# ppoll() vs. pselect() with multiple threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, network-programming

I want to use ppoll or pselect in multithreaded program. According to man pages ([ppoll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ppoll), [pselect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect)), there is significant difference between them - ppol is said to use (or behave like using) sigprocmask, and pselect to use pthread_sigmask. And on the sigprocmask man page is information "The use of sigprocmask() is unspecified in a multithreaded process; see pthread_sigmask(3)".

Does it mean, that I have to use pselect, and not ppoll? Is it real difference, or only diffrence/error/inaccuracy in man?

I've just spotted, that in man pages in my system both pselect and ppoll are described as using equvalent to sigprocmask. Is it difference in pselect or just in man?

Comment: Both are genuine syscalls on a recent Linux kernel (e.g. 3.8 at least). So it should not make big difference, but I suggest `ppoll` (for the reasons known in the C10K problem)

Comment: While you're investigating approaches, have you considered using `epoll`?

Comment: I would suggest talking a look at [epoll()](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) also because of the C10K.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about efficiency (or maybe I am, this threads are not so very necessary...), so I didn't thought about using epoll (however I know about it). On the other hand it is described as behaving like sigprocmask too - can I suppose, that it actually behaves like pthread_sigmask?

Thank for your answers, I'll consider using epoll once more.